# Dataclass not inheriting __eq__() method from its parent

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I have a parent dataclass and a sub-dataclass inherits the first class. I've redefined `__eq__()` method in parent dataclass. But when I compare objects sub-dataclass, it doesn't use the `__eq__()` method defined in parent dataclass. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

**MWE**:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class A:
    name: str
    field1: str = None

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('A class eq')
        return self.name == other.name


@dataclass
class B(A):
    field2: str = None


b1 = B('b', 'b1')
b2 = B('b', 'b2')
print(b1 == b2)
```

Comment: I think the `@dataclass` decorator adds a default `__eq__` implementation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `@dataclass` decorator adds a default `__eq__` implementation.

If you use

```
@dataclass(eq=False)
```

on class B, it will avoid doing that.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Answer (score 4):

By default, the `dataclass` decorator generates an `__eq__` method for the decorated class. To disable this (allowing `B` to inherit `A.__eq__`), you need to adjust the decorator.

```
@dataclass(eq=False)
class B(A):
    field2: str = None
```

Comment: The generated `__eq__` won't invoke the base class `__eq__`? I'd expect the base class one to check the base class members, and for the derived class one to invoke it to check the base class members then go on to check the derived class ones itself.

Comment: The generated method compares all applicable fields, including those inherited from the base class, instead of calling the base-class method explicitly.

Comment: When the base class isn't a dataclass it appears to ignore the fields from the base entirely, which seems like a footgun.

Comment: If the base class isn't a dataclass, it doesn't *have* fields. "Field" isn't just a synonym for "instance attribute" here; it's a specific kind of object that the `dataclass` decorator uses to generate methods. The *user* doesn't need to define `Field` objects explicitly, though they can using `dataclasses.field`: `dataclass` can use the class's annotations and class attributes to define them.

Comment: All of which is to say, trying to define a dataclass using a non-dataclass base class is probably not a good idea.